# In a responsive 1 to 2 column layout - how to specify if a DIV is to be stacked in column 1 or column 2?

Tags: css, css-float, masonry

On mobile I have 1 column of DIVs of different heights.
Using CSS, on larger screens I would like 2 columns, with DIVs I specify stacked in the left column, and the others stacked in the right column (per image below).
I was thinking div-class="right" for some and div-class="left" for others.
Is there a way to do this with floats or do I have to go a masonry route?

https://imgur.com/a/Zalc0qO

Answer (score 0):

you can try display:flex. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using flex; see code below for an example.

```css
.container {
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  width: 440px; 
  border: 2px solid red; 
}

.child {
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px; 
  margin: 10px; 
  background: blue; 
  
}


  .child.left {
    background: green; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child left"></div>
  <div class="child right"></div>
  <div class="child left"></div>
  <div class="child right"></div>
  <div class="child left"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen to play around with. If you alter the width of the container you can see the behavior.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WaGNzp)